# Elasticsearch Searching and Sorting Error: Parsing Exception - Malformed Query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am working on implementing searching and sorting functionality using Elasticsearch in my Java application. I am using Elasticsearch version 8.10.4 and Spring Data Elasticsearch version 5.1.5. When I try to perform a search operation along with sorting, I am encountering the following error:

```
co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.ElasticsearchException: [es/search] failed: [parsing_exception] [bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]
at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:334) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.7.1.jar:na]
at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:154) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.7.1.jar:na]
at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1882) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.7.1.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.ElasticsearchTemplate.lambda$count$13(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:319) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-5.1.5.jar:5.1.5]
```

I am using a bool query for combining multiple match queries, and I suspect there might be an issue with the query structure. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
@Query("{\"bool\": {\"should\": [" +
        "{\"match\": {\"name\": \"?0\"}}, " +
        "{\"match\": {\"email\": \"?1\"}}, " +
        "{\"match\": {\"address\": \"?2\"}}, " +
        "{\"match\": {\"phone\": \"?3\"}}" +
        "]}," +
        "\"sort\": [{\"sortField\": \"?4\"}, {\"sortOrder\": \"?5\"}]}}")
List<User> partialSearch(String name, String email, String address, String phone, String sortField, String sortOrder);
```

I have double-checked the query syntax, and it seems correct to me. Could you please help me identify the issue and provide guidance on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `@Query` is the only the query part of a search request, not any sorting or filter parameters (please use text blocks instead of theat unreadable `\"` escaping). You have to pass these with an additional parameter of the type `Sort`:

```java
@Query("""
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {"name": "?0"}
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {"email": "?1"}
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {"address": "?2"}
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {"phone": "?3"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
                """)
List<User> partialSearch(String name, String email, String address, String phone, Sort sort);
```

At the place where this method is called you build the Sort like this:

```java
var sort = Sort.by(sortField).ascending(); // or use .descending()
var users = partialSearch(name, email, address, phone, sort)
```

As an alternative for specifiying the query part for a simple search like this, you could just define a repository method like this:

```java
List<Users> findByNameAndEmailAndAddressAndPhone(String, name, String email, String address, String phone, Sort sort);
```

and let Spring Data Elasticsearch handle the query building, see the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods)

Comment: thanks for the response, `List<Users> findByNameAndEmailAndAddressAndPhone(Sort sort);` but how i can pass all the mentioned parameters in method??

Comment: my error, I fixed the method definition and linked the reference docs